# 3D soft body physics with Ammo.js?

Tags: game-physics, bullet, physics-engine, bulletphysics, ammo.js

I'm told that soft body physics wasn't ported over to Ammo.js. So a few questions:

- Why? Would it be too computationally intensive for JavaScript?
- Are there any JavaScript builds which include the soft body physics part of the Bullet engine?
- Is Bullet's soft body physics reliable enough for me to be attempting to play around with a JavaScript version?

EDIT1: Oh and as a backup: if it's not possible or very hard with Ammo.js, are there other alternatives?

Comment: You're better off asking the people responsible for the port directly why they didn't port that part of the engine.

Comment: @weston Ah k thanks! I'll ask on github and post any answers back here

Answer (score 1):

It has not been ported because no one has done it yet - no big reason. Seems like Bullet's soft body stuff should run fine in JavaScript. See:

https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js/issues/83